How curve is inextendible?
I am reading a literature arXiv:1901.03928v6  [hep-th]  12 Jul 2023 and it says :

In Minkowski space, the timelike geodesic $(t(s),x(s))=(s,0)$ is inextendible if $s$ is regarded as a real variable.

First of all, how do we write timelike geodesic for this and secondly how this curve is inextendible?
Then it says

but if we arbitrarily restrict $s$ to a subset of real line, for example $0<s<1$, we get an extendible causal curve.

I don't understand why the previous one is inextendible and this one is extendible?
I know if a curve is inextendible then it can not be extended further but I am also following more general (mathematical) definition from this post
Future inextendible curve
How can we apply this definition here?

I think that the thing you're missing in the answer to the post you've linked to, is the fact that a future inextendible curve has no endpoint in spacetime. As the author of the answer wrote:

$\gamma$ is future inextendible if there is no point $p$ in the spacetime such that $\gamma(t)\to p$ for $t\to b^-$.

Note that $(s,0)$ with $s\rightarrow \infty$ isn't a point in spacetime. Hence the first curve you mention has no endpoint, which by definition means it is indeed inextendible.
This also answers the second part of your question - if the parameter $s$ is bounded from above, the curve may be future extendible. In the example you give, it indeed is (when $s\in(0,1)$), because the spatial component is specified to be a constant according to the first part of your post, leading to the curve having a well defined endpoint.

Edit - as per your request, I'll also answer this part:

First of all, how do we write timelike geodesic for this

Note that we're assuming Minkowski space, so it is easy to verify $\gamma$ satisfies the geodesic equation:
$$\ddot{\gamma}^i+\Gamma^i_{jk}\dot{\gamma}^j\dot{\gamma}^k=0,$$
since $\ddot{\gamma}=0$ and with the Minkowski metric we have $\Gamma^i_{jk}=0$.
This shows the curve is a geodesic. It is also clearly timelike because $\dot{\gamma}=(1,0)$, a manifestly timelike vector. Also refer to this answer for a rigorous definition of a timelike geodesic.

And how do we write timelike geodesic for this $(s,0)$?

@TalhaAhmed See edited answer.

Thank you so much. I got it now

@Talha Ahmed Since you used my answer to your other question, I assume that you consider it correct. If it is the case, you could accept it….

@ValterMoretti sorry, I forgot that. just accepted now
